# Aggregating unique character values per group in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, uniqueidentifier

I want to aggregate all the keywords in a specific year by groups.

I have a dataset that looks like this: 
[image]

Primary problem for me is that *Words* column can vary between 1 and 52! I was thinking of splitting this column in different columns and then use group_by. But now I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Please note that it’s best to avoid using images of code/data and [here’s why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). You can quickly get your data out of your R session and onto SO by calling `dput(my_df)` and copy/pasting the result.  If your data are large, do `dput(head(my_df))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can split the 'Words' into a `list` of `vector`s, `unnest` into 'long' format, remove the duplicate rows, grouped by 'Year', 'UID', `paste` the 'Words' into a single string

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Words = strsplit(Words, ",")) %>% 
    unnest %>% 
    distinct(Year, UID, Words) %>% 
    group_by(UID, Year) %>% 
    summarise(Words = toString(Words))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   UID [?]
#    UID  Year Words                                    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                                    
#1    10  2009 ABC, CDEFGH, LMX, ABCD, IJKLM, PQRS, EFGH
#2    11  2010 BDFC, CDE, PQRS, ACCA, IJKLM             
#3    12  2010 ABCD, CADDE                              
#4    12  2011 ABC, CDE, EFGH
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5), Year = c(2011, 2011, 
2010, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2009), UID = c(12, 12, 11, 12, 10, 11, 
10), Words = c("ABC,CDE", "EFGH,CDE", "BDFC,CDE,PQRS", "ABCD,CADDE", 
"ABC,CDEFGH,LMX,ABCD,IJKLM,PQRS", "BDFC,ACCA,IJKLM", "EFGH")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! There is mistake in my post. ID is unique.

Comment: @ShivKumar  It's okay, we are not using the 'ID'

Comment: @akrun, how to implement your answer in data.table approach, please? I would be very grateful for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

A Base R approach with `aggregate`:

```
df <- data.frame(
    id = c(1:5, 6, 5),
    year = c(2011, 2011, 2010, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2009),
    uid = c(12, 12, 11, 12, 10, 11, 10),
    words = c("abc,cde", "efgh,cde", "bdfc,cde,pqrs", "abcd,cadde", "abc,cdefgh,lmx,abcd,ijklm,pqrs","bdfc,acca,ijklm", "efgh"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

aggregate(df["words"], df[,c("year", "uid")], function(x) paste0(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))), collapse=","))
```